# Line before and after text, with text in the middle and button on the right

Tags: html, css

I have added a line on either side of text, with the text being in the middle and a button on the right after the line on the right, and the line is overlapping the button, where as i want the after line just touching the border of the button so it blends in nicely. I have tried most of the day and every time i try to edit the css. It seems to either move the text or the left line, or event make the lines smaller.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
<h1>Latest News</h1>
<button><a href="#">More</a></button>
</div>
```

And here is my css:

```
.main h1 {
overflow: hidden;
text-align: center;
}
.main h1:before,
.main h1:after {
background-color: #000;
content: "";
display: inline-block;
height: 1px;
position: relative;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 50%;
}
.main h1:before {
right: 0.5em;
margin-left: -50%;
}
.main h1:after {
left: 0.5em;
margin-right: -50%;
}
.main button {
float: right;
width: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #000;
margin-top: -50px;
}
.main a {
font-size: 20px;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Line before and after text with button on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67EVk.png)

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest drop-in solution is to specify a negative `z-index` for the `h1::after` pseudo-element:

```
.main h1:after {
  left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```css
.main h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.main h1:before,
.main h1:after {
  background-color: #000;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 50%;
}

.main h1:before {
  right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: -50%;
}

.main h1:after {
  left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.main button {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.main a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <h1>Latest News</h1>
  <button><a href="#">More</a></button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kvae3d9r/).

References:

- [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).